# XCode, present code coverage percent

Tags: xcode, code-coverage

How can I display the percent of the file\function in the code coverage report ? Currently I can view it only by tooltip while marking specific file\function.
to see a numerical value without hovering,

Can I add some percent column somehow ?

I read that there is some rdar://21531774 but could not fine it

Thanks,
Ronen

Comment: You can use a hosted solution like Codecov (https://codecov.io): https://github.com/codecov/example-xcode Thank you

Comment: ok, thank you , I'll try it